# whats the meaning of country doctor?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have been reading "the gioconda smile". one expression that I do not know well. what is the meaning of "country doctor"?

Answer (score 1):

A **country doctor** is a doctor whose practice is in the countryside or rural areas, away from all the facilities of a big city hospital. There are additional challenges for these doctors due to reduced resources for treating patients.

One of the most famous groups of country doctors were the "[barefoot doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot_doctor)" in China during the early days of communism and the Cultural Revolution.

[image: here]

Comment: +1. Only a single use of bolding! Great. (0: "*[The bridge at midnight trembles, the country doctor rambles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w1mCevu3sU)*" (Dylan)

Comment: -2 or 3. First, the bolded phrase is still an eyesore. Second, the reference to barefoot doctors is largely irrelevant to the usage of "country doctor" in a short story by Huxley published in the 1920s. The photo is misplaced and a mismatch to the question. It could prove misleading. Fourth, most barefoot doctors were not doctors.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Peter is not obligated to follow the style of your choice or preference. Furthermore, you don't have the right to edit the post that way. If you have a different opinion or answer, post your own answer.